# Change the height of a Seaborn heatmap colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap, seaborn, colorbar

I have the following Python code to create a heatmap using the Seaborn package:

```
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(21,5))
heatmap = sns.heatmap(significantBig5[basic].as_matrix().T,mask=labelsDf.T,
     annot=False,fmt='.2f',yticklabels=basic_labels,linewidths=0.5,square=True,
     xticklabels=traits)
plt.xticks(rotation=70)
```

This creates the following heatmap:
[image: sample heatmap]

I would like to format this heatmap so that the colorbar on the right side is shorter. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `cbar_ax` argument and set position of color bar you like:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

arr = np.random.random((1,9))
df = pd.DataFrame(arr)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
cbar_ax = fig.add_axes([.905, .3, .05, .3])
sns.heatmap(arr, ax=ax, cbar_ax = cbar_ax, cbar=True)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 30):

You can also use the extra keyword arguments for the sns heatmap colorbar the cbar_kws. They modify the settings for the matplotlib colorbar documented [here](https://matplotlib.org/api/colorbar_api.html#matplotlib.colorbar.Colorbar)

Using the code of @Serenity with the shrinkage keyword we get this:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

arr = np.random.random((1,9))
df = pd.DataFrame(arr)
sns.heatmap(arr,cbar=True,cbar_kws={"shrink": .82})

plt.show()
```

[image]